# Knowing the existence of a fixed point set from an induced fundamental group automorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

Let $L$ be a link in $S^{3} $ and $f_{ \phi } : \pi_{1} (S^{3} \backslash L ) \rightarrow  \pi_{1} (S^{3} \backslash L )$ be induced from a periodic map $\phi $  of $S^{3} $, restricted to the complement, with $\phi (L ) = L $. Can I know if $\phi $ has a fixed point set disjoint of $L$ by knowing $f_{ \phi }$?

Comment: what's a periodic map?

Comment: A homeomorphism with $f^{n}$ the identity for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: Just a thought. If $f_{\phi}$ has no fixed points, then because it is a homeomorphism, and has finite order as an element of the mapping class group of $S^3\setminus L$, the orbit-space $O_{f_{\phi}}=(S^3\setminus L)/ f_{\phi}$ has an $m$-fold cover by $S^3\setminus L$ with $m\mid n$. This puts certain constraints on the knot-group of $L$. In particular, $0\to\mathbb{Z}_m\to\pi_1(S^3\setminus L)\stackrel{(f_{\phi})_*}{\to}\pi_1(O_{f_{\phi}})\to 0$ is a short exact sequence of groups.